# How to open webview with header and footer in Phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

i have a requirement in application where i want to open webview with custom header and footer, i have already used Inappbrowser but it opens webview but we can't customize or add header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, There is a need to use [Embedded cordowa webview](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html) in your android layout xml.

and use your header and footer.
  like

```
<LinearLayout>
header
</LinearLayout>


<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout>
footer
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do u have any idea for ios ?

Comment: how to open webview with custom header in ios ?

Comment: do u know how to integrate the cordova webview

Comment: what is the purpose of cordova webview in ios ..i dont know,if u know can u pls explain it.

Comment: it is for native application which want to integrate phonegap html page .

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android_guide_to_using_cordovawebview_in_an_android_project

Comment: how to fetch with fb api all fb frnd list and b'date ?

Comment: is there any api for fetch list ?